# I would like to join 2 tables based on a field 'LIKE' the contents of another field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to join 2 tables based on a field value in the first table that is a complete value, and 'like'ing to the variable contents of another field in the second table...

e.g.

Table A contains 2 columns as `NAME = 'Bob'` and `JOB = 'Builder'`
Table B contains 2 columns as `REVIEW = 'Good'` and `TITLE = 'This Builder is recommended'`

my query would be...

```
SELECT A.NAME, B.REVIEW
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.JOB LIKE %(B.TITLE)%
```

My question is how to format the second part of the `LIKE` clause as i want to build the wildcards around the results of the results of the db field rather than a fixed value.

I have tried `" LIKE '%' + B.TITLE + '%'` as recommended in another question but this is returning nothing.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You need to swap the columns in the comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the other way around and you need to concatenate the wildcard chars and the column value:

```
SELECT A.NAME, B.REVIEW
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON B.TITLE LIKE concat('%', A.JOB, '%')
```

Comment: Borrowing this answer if that's ok. Did'nt know you could join like this. What happens if the `like` gets multiple hits?

Comment: *multiple hits* meaning?

Comment: If your `like` was, for example `like '%A%` and you have lots of rows matching on that. Don't this have a big risk of getting huge or unforeseen results back?

Comment: This is an INNER JOIN. If `B.TITLE LIKE concat('%', A.JOB, '%')` is TRUE then the 2 rows will be joined. In the OP's sample data, the row from Table B with `TITLE = 'This Builder is recommended'` will be joined to any row from Table A with `JOB = 'Builder'`. If there are many rows with this value then all will be joined because this is the expected result. There is nothing unforeseen here.

Comment: I did'nt mean in this specific question. It was more of a general question about joining on `like`.

Comment: Even so, LIKE poses a condition just like a `a.id = b.id` and if the condition is met then the rows are joined.

Comment: Thanks @forpas, that has worked a treat, never thought to switch it like that.